# What does "set yourself up for" meaning in this sentece?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "set yourself up for" meaning in this sentece?

> Another one of the best ways to make your New Year’s resolutions
>   stick: Don’t set yourself up for failure with goals that aren’t
>   realistic.

Source link : https://www.thehealthy.com/habits/new-year-health-mistakes/

Answer (score 2):

Don't put yourself into an impossible or difficult situation.

A popular phrase is "*don't set yourself up for a fall*", meaning don't continue with an action that is destined for failure.

Comment: Just so it's clear, *set yourself up for something* isn't inherently negative in meaning:  e.g., a popular expression is also *set yourself up for success*. In other words, *set X up for Y* means to make the circumstances surrounding X situation conducive to Y. For more information, see https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/set+yourself+up+for.